# SQL*Plus shows invalid character with single quotes

Tags: sql, oracle

What' the error with this syntax?

```
SELECT empno, sal*.075, ROUND(sal*.075, 2) bonus FROM emp WHERE ename LIKE ‘%A%’;
```

The sql statement which gives no error is the one written below.

```
SELECT empno, sal*.075, ROUND(sal*.075, 2) bonus FROM emp WHERE ename LIKE '%A%';
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
‘%A%’;
```

v.s.

```
'%A%';
```

The first has fancy `'` characters.  The usual cause for that is Outlook's AutoCorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the 1st is the single quote. `SQL` doesn't accept that quote. I dont find the one in my keyboard. May be you copied the query from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `‘%A%’`. SQL doesn't accept this character - this should be `'%A%'`.

I could not find this in my keyboard.